# Auto Layout Constraints not showing up in Build (iOS/Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I am attempting to position a label in a custom table view cell... but not having much luck...

My table view comprises two custom cells. For my first custom cell, all the auto layout constraints have worked as expected. But for the second custom cell, while I add the constraints as before (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrAir.png)), they do not show up in my test builds.

[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrAir.png)

On top of this, when I then look for the constraints in debug view hierarchy, they again don't show up.

Any sage advice would be massively appreciated! (This is driving me insane...)

Comment: Can you upload your project to github?

Comment: Is the second cell showing up in the test build?

Comment: Thanks for offers of help on this. I just rebuilt the whole page in StoryBoard in a frenzy, which seems to have fixed the problem..